# interesting problem with map<char*, int>

Tags: c++

```
char* a = "aaa";

map<char*, int> m;   
m.insert(pair<char*, int>(a,5));    

a[0] = 'c';
a[1] = 'c';
a[2] = 'c';

cout << a << endl; // a = `ccc`
cout << m["aaa"] << endl; // found the node by `aaa`,
cout << m.begin()->first << endl; // but the node's left is actually `ccc`?
```

So the node's left is `ccc` or `aaa`?

Comment: The question is very unclear.

Comment: You're attempting to modify a read-only string literal. The result will be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it does not found the node by "aaa" nor "ccc", it founds the node by the memory address `a` points to. Comparison between pointers does just that, it does not perform a string comparison. If you want to index by a string, then use an `std::string`.

Comment: char* a and m["aaa"] should have different memory addresses, then how could the node be found by memory address?

Comment: @user956159: No, there are no guarantees that they will have different memory addresses. String literals are inmutable, so the compiler can make them all point to the same memory, but it does not have to either.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't understand the question properly. Still, there are few things in your code I would like to comment on, such as:

```
char* a = "aaa";
```

This is deprecated. Didn't your compiler give  warning message? It should be written as:

```
const char* a = "aaa";
```

---

```
a[0] = 'c'; //it should be an error if you correctly declare `a`
a[1] = 'c'; //it should be an error if you correctly declare `a`
a[2] = 'c'; //it should be an error if you correctly declare `a`
```

It's precisely because you shouldn't do this, the declaraton of `a` in your code is deprecated. If you declare `a` as I suggested (which is correct also), then the compiler would give *error* for the above assignment statements.

Moreover, if `a` is `const char*`, then your question *"the node's left is ccc or aaa?"* wouldn't arise in the first place. Because `a` is after all points to `const` data, and so you cannot change it, thus `m.begin()->first` will always be `aaa`.

Also, the `map` declaration should be:

```
map<const char*, int> m;
```

Or even better would be this:

```
map<std::string, int> m;
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer prpperly. ;)

Comment: @muntoo: Thanks for the edit. And I edited it as well. Hope you understand it now.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The type of the string literal `"aaa"` is `const char[4]`. Despite the type of `a` being `char*` (pointer to modifiable char), you've made it point to a read-only memory location.

The line `a[0] = 'c';` invokes undefined behavior and, on most compilers, a runtime failure.

Your compiler, apparently, permitted your program to modify the value of the literal `"aaa"` in this manner, so that the values "ccc" were stored at its memory location. However, when you asked the compiler to generate a pointer to `"aaa"` again later on, it produced the same address of what it thought was the string "aaa" in its static data section,